# Is there a way to validate the routing key format or a message schema for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I am using RabbitMQ as a message broker. I have an An API that accepts the message from another process and uses the python pika library to send the message to RabbitMQ. I want to validate two things:

1. The format of the routing key is in an expected format (for example, we expect the routing key to be something like `<data-type>.<update-stage>.<success|failure>`
2. The message follows the json schema expected by the consumers.

I know that I can easily do the validation at the API level, but I was wondering if RabbitMQ itself has any way to register schemas or validate the format of the routing key, and if this validation is doable within the pika library.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if RabbitMQ itself has any way to register schemas or validate the format of the routing key, and if this validation is doable within the pika library

No, this is not supported out-of-the box.

You should be able to accomplish it via a custom RabbitMQ plugin. You could use the [Message Timestamp plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp) as a guide.

In fact, this is an interesting enough problem I will give it a shot. Subscribe to this repository -

https://github.com/lukebakken/rabbitmq-message-validator

I have imported the message timestamp plugin code there and will migrate it to a validator.

Please open a GitHub issue there to introduce yourself and I will add you as a collaborator to my repository.